# Tomcat + ActiveJDBC: open/close connection using servlet filter?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet-filters, activejdbc

My web application uses ActiveJDBC.  This ORM framework requires to open new DB connection with every new thread (and of course close it when the thread finishes).  I am wondering if the best way to achieve this is to use a Web Filter.

if this is the case, where do I call `Base.open()`? the options are `init()` or `doFilter()`.  also, if I plan to call `Base.close()` in `destroy()`, I need to know that indeed `destroy()` is always called at the thread termination, whether it is normal or abnormal.

EDIT: after reading about servlet filters, I now believe that the proper processing would be to open and close the connection in `doFilter()`:

```
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException { 
  Base.open();
  chain.doFilter(request,wrapper);
  Base.close(); 
}
```

is this the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct way of opening and closing a connection for ActiveJDBC in a web environment.

In addition to that,  this is the right place to manage exceptions. For instance, you might want to manage transactions like this:

```
try{
  Base.openTransaction(); 
  chain.doFilter(request,wrapper);
  Base.commitTransaction(); 
}catch(Exception e){
  // log exception
  Base.rollbackTransaction();
}finally{
  Base.close();
}
```

Ultimately rather than dealing with Servlets, why not give [ActiveWeb](http://javalite.io/activeweb) a spin? See more here: http://javalite.io/database_configuration

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct implementation however, to scale up your application you may want a database connection pooler in which case you will want to keep your connections alive even after you do your db operations.

Comment: what makes you think I dont use connection pool? even in connection pool, you do conn.close() to return it to the pool...