# Java Servlet activejdbc NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, servlets, activejdbc

I'm trying to use ActiveJDBC inside a HttpServlet - I understand that the DB connection needs to opened on a seperate thread, and [can be done through a WebFilter.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485175/tomcat-activejdbc-open-close-connection-using-servlet-filter)

Unfortunately im snagging at this error message:

> Exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
>   Root Cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.javalite.activejdbc.Registry
>     org.javalite.activejdbc.DB.open(DB.java:152)
>     org.javalite.activejdbc.Base.open(Base.java:51)
>     filters.DBFilter.doFilter(DBFilter.java:13)

Full Error Stack:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.javalite.activejdbc.Registry
    at org.javalite.activejdbc.DB.open(DB.java:152)
    at org.javalite.activejdbc.Base.open(Base.java:51)
    at filters.DBFilter.init(DBFilter.java:17)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4491)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1858)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:772)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1629)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1370)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here's my filters.DBFilter class:

```
package filters;

import org.javalite.activejdbc.Base;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebFilter("/DBFilter")
public class DBFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Base.open();
        chain.doFilter(request,response);
        Base.close();
    }
}
```

And complete `.classpath`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="target/generated-sources/annotations">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="ignore_optional_problems" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="m2e-apt" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="ignore_optional_problems" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="m2e-apt" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

And complete `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.ticketsit</groupId>
  <artifactId>ticketsit</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>ticketsit Maven Webapp</name>

  <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
      <environments>development.test,development</environments>
      <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.javalite</groupId>
      <artifactId>activejdbc</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
          <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>mysql</groupId>
          <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
          <version>8.0.13</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.javalite</groupId>
          <artifactId>activejdbc-instrumentation</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
      </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>ticketsit</finalName>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes><exclude>node_modules/**</exclude></excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.javalite</groupId>
              <artifactId>activejdbc-instrumentation</artifactId>
              <version>2.0</version>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <phase>process-classes</phase>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>instrument</goal>
                      </goals>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
          </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Any ideas what's wrong? Thank-you.

Comment: Check your classpath. NoClassDefFoundError means that the ActiveJDBC JAR is not in your classpath.

Comment: Please post entire stack trace

Comment: It has to do with your server not refreshing the changes. Restart your server and it will work.

Comment: @vanje I've updated my issue with `.classpath`, is there anything you notice that's off?

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte I have refreshed and tried in multiple Tomcat servers, but there's no difference

Comment: @TheMintyMate it looks like it has to do with the package javalite that you're using. It's missing classes. post your pom.xml

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte Posted the `pom.xml` - cheers

Comment: try remove the second javalite dependency you have in your pom the one with artifactId: "activejdbc-instrumentation"

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte Removed and re-compiled, same error stack has appeared. (this dependancy is needed to instrument the Model classes, though it's the plugin which is actively used from what I can tell)

Comment: what is Base.open() and Base.close() supposed to do here? in your filter

Comment: Its supposed to make a database connection available to any Servlets (and Active Models) that the filter is matched to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485175/tomcat-activejdbc-open-close-connection-using-servlet-filter?noredirect=1&lq=1 I'll try wrapping it in a try and catch - should have done this anyway

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte Can you believe it... it all came down to the `try{} catch{}`... *sighs inwardly with disapointment* Cheers for looking at this mate :-)

Comment: Haha glad to hear you found out the problem. Your IDE should really have told you're missing a try catch block!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must setup a `try{} catch{}` wrapper, optionally with transactions. Unfortunately the error message doesn't exactly reveal this problem clearly!

Example:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    chain.doFilter(request,response);
    try{
        Base.open();
        Base.openTransaction();
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        Base.commitTransaction();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        Base.rollbackTransaction();
        throw e;
    }
    catch (ServletException e){
        Base.rollbackTransaction();
        throw e;
    }
    finally{
        Base.close();
    }
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38485898/5865284

Answer (score -1):

Try to delete `activejdbc-xxx.jar` in your `tomcat\webapps\...\WEB-INF\lib` and put it again

Not sure if it works for you, at least this is how I solved it.